# How can I implement connected jcarousel views?

Tags: views

I know drupal has [jcarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) and  [views slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) modules and work with each of them some times, I want to create something like this [link](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/connected-carousels/) ( images list below with carousel and when click on each one the big image changed), I know  I can create  a slide show that thumbnail image be below of big image and when click on them the big image changed (but this is not carousel, it means all images listed below big image without next and prev ),
**Anybody has idea how can I implement `connected-carousels` in views?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Views Slideshow JCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_jcarousel) module, it is a combination of jcarousel and slideshow modules.

Answer (score 1):

You need [Views Slideshow JCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_jcarousel) which provides the same functionality. It will add jcarousel pager in slideshow settings. ;)